# cwl files not rendering autocompletion

Tags: texstudio, auto-completion

I am using TeXstudio 4.2.3 on Mac.

So, I start with a blank folder and create an `abc.sty` file, defining some `\newcommand`s. I then use that package in, say `abc.tex` file, that I create in the same folder. But I don't see autocompletion happening while typing in `abc.tex`.

I have checked that the folder `/Users/atom/.config/texstudio/completion/autogenerated` does contain the cal file `abc.cwl`. I have also tried relaunching TeXstudio, but to no use.

What is misbehaving here? And how can I rectify it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Autogenerated cwls give every command the `#S` marker, which tells the highlighter to recognize the command but not show in the completer. If you want these commands to be auto-completed, just open `abc.cwl` and remove the `#S` from each line. Then save the file and restart texstudio.

Comment: This worked! +1. But, is there a way to not go through the laborious task of deleting `#S` from *each* line?

Comment: You can use the "Replace All" feature of any text editor.